# ( SQLite + FileSystemWatcher) SQLite.NET Async Connection not working for Bulk Insert (20+). All Records are not inserted

Tags: c#, sqlite, filesystemwatcher, sqlite-net

**Sync Program**

We've a Sync Application/ Program. This Program Mirrors the files/ folders in the sync Directory (say D:\SyncDir) on the server as and when it's Created/ Copied/ Renamed/ Deleted.

**Technology**

It's a Windows Form Application.

This Sync Program watches the Sync Directory (say D:\SyncDir) through .NET FileSystemWatcher class.

There're situation when even 1000+ files/ directories are copied to the Sync location (D:\SyncDir).

I'm using SQLite Database to store the path of the files/directory copied into Sync Location. Then, I've a logic which read the SQLite table and one-by-one uploads the file/directory on the server.

**Challenges:**

Suppose 100+ files/ folders are copied, it writes just 10-12 files into SQLite table.
If number of files/ folders are less (<15) it works well.

I'm suing one SQLiteAsync.cs

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please debug and try to find out whether `FileSystemWatcher` detecting file changes correctly or not. If `FileSystemWatcher ` is not detecting correctly, please remove  `sqlite` tag from the question.

Comment: Hello  Moshii, thanks for your reply. I checked, FileSystemWatcher is detecting all the files correctly(even if its 100+). Just when I'm trying to write it into SQLite DB it write only 20/30 records.

Comment: Could you share your code, please?